# Concatenating files in a directory, changing the format

Tags: python, pandas, file, concatenation

I have many files in a directory that starts with prefix "AA_". Those files have missing values and I am sharing the short version given below:

```
AA_1.txt:
    year, month, day, hour, price
    1990, 01,    01,  01,   100
    1990, 01,    01,  02,   200
    1990, 01,    01,  03,   NA
    1990, 01,    01,  04,   300

AA_2.txt:
    year, month, day, hour, price
    1990, 01,    02,  01,   130
    1990, 01,    02,  02,   120
    1990, 01,    02,  03,   NA
    1990, 01,    02,  04,   700
```

I am trying to get the format of concatenated version of {AA_1.txt, AA_2.txt, ..} files inside a directory:

```
merged.txt:
        date            price
        1990-01-01:01,   100
        1990-01-01:02,   200
        1990-01-01:03,   NA
        1990-01-01:04,   300
        1990-01-02:01,   130
        1990-01-02:02,   120
        1990-01-02:03,   NA
        1990-01-02:04,   700
```

Can you please help me to implement this in Python?

Comment: What you have you tried so far?

Comment: share the current effort, explain what is the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a shell one-liner:

```
head -1 AA_1.txt; { tail -n +2 AA_1.txt; tail -n +2 AA_2.txt; } | sort | sed 's/, */-/; s/, */-/; s/, */:/'
```

Leaving it as an exercise to reader to port it to python, say, by wrapping it in `os.system` call.